# Is there anything that prevents stack overflow in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, theory

In assembly language programming, what (if anything) prevents a stack from growing until it clobbers data or instructions?

Comment: ... there is no compiler in *assembly* language programming...  Do you mean assembler?  (As far as I know assemblers simply convert mnemonics to machine code, doing very little structural checking along the way.)

Comment: to assemble = to put something together... to compile = to ... ummm... put something together???

Comment: The distinction is around the complexity of the program that is 'putting the things together'.  Assemblers are much simpler programs than compilers.  And as far as I know, assemblers don't do much checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what (if anything) prevents a stack from growing and clobbering data
>   or instructions?

YOU!  There is absolutely no hand holding when coding in Assembly.  You must make sure all values fit into their buffers, all pointer indexes are within bounds.  You reserve space on the stack, make sure whatever fits into that buffer.  YOU are responsible for every aspect of programming while using Assembly.

Comment: I thought that might be the answer... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Only the CPU/MMU configuration, which is usually done by the OS, can prevent or intercept stack overflows and memory corruptions or attempts to access something without the necessary privileges.

You can read the chapters on memory management in the x86 CPU manuals from Intel/AMD to find out more.

Comment: After further investigation, the x86 CPU manuals are quite **enormous**... do you have any reference or keywords in mind that might point more directly to the material you're referring to, i.e. what the OS does to help and how?

Comment: Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3A: ch.3 "Protected-Mode Memory Management", ch.4 "Paging", ch.5 "Protection" and some parts of ch.6 "Interrupt and Exception Handling".

Comment: Usually, The OS doesn't help much. It can never "understand" a program and "fix" it. It can only notice something going very wrong and terminate the problematic process. Sometimes, the process can intervene by requesting that the OS redirect exception handling to the process itself (see Structured Exception Handling (SEH) in Windows). But that doesn't quite work for stack overflows, because if there's no more stack, the in-process exception handler can't do any meaningful work or recovery as it needs some stack and there's none.

Comment: Makes sense about the OS having limited ability to intervene.  Any OS intervention would have to come through a superuser type watchdog process that was quite intrusive on each program, monitoring the stack, etc.  It is probably the case that **Gunners** answer of 'the programmer', and the use of techniques such as canaries (suggested by **nrz**) is the solution.  I'll check out the chapters you listed.

Comment: I would assume that the OS can (and usually will) leave a gap in the address range between heap and stack. A user space process accessing data in that gap would therefore cause a page fault, which could get reported back to the application e.g. in the form of a call to the segmentation fault signal handler.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [canaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries) directly below the accepted lower bound of stack and check the canaries' values constantly.

In kernelland code (ring 0) you can also set a [hardware breakpoint](http://ftp.utcluj.ro/pub/users/nedevschi/PMP/protected86/protgemode/translate_cdebugreg.html) by setting the value of one of the debug registers `dr0`, `dr1`, `dr2` and `dr3` to the linear address of the breakpoint address, directly below the accepted lower bound of stack and then setting the correct flag bit of `dr7` register, and report or try to fix the situation in the breakpoint handler code. See [HardWare BreakPoints The Definitive Guide](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/31445884/HardWare-BreakPoints-The-Definitive-Guide).

Comment: That's an interesting approach (extra layer of code protection).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

99.99% of reasons for stack overflow is a program bug or bad program design.

Now we have two basic but out of this topic questions:

> 1)How to prevent bugs in assembly?
>
> 2)How to do good program design?

Comment: True, though I was asking specifically to understand whether there were any mechanisms for preventing stack overflow, bugs and poor program design notwithstanding.